# Ruby threads: methods and instances of objects

Tags: ruby, multithreading

Consider the below snippet. In it, I define a single method called `doit`, which subsequently gets called from two different threads.

Contrary to what I expect, `t.object_id` in the method keeps returning two distinct IDs, as if the call to the method from each thread received its own space in memory.

What I expected to happen was that on the second thread entering the method, it would replace the Hash previously defined, resulting in the same object ID being printed the rest of the time. In other words, I thought there would have been a single instance of the Hash.

Arguably, this would have suggested that the loop in the first entry of the method would have blocked any subsequent access thereto, but this is obviously not the case.

So what is the deal with methods? Does each invocation from a separate thread receive its own copy in memory? What is the correct way to understand this?

```
def doit
    t = Hash.new
    puts t.object_id
    loop do
      sleep 1
      puts t.object_id
    end
end

t1 = Thread.new { doit }
t2 = Thread.new { doit }

t1.join
t2.join
```

By way of example, this is the output:

```
21329316
21327684
21329316
21327684
21329316
21327684
21327684
21329316
21327684
21329316
21327684
21329316
```

Comment: The result is as expected, I think these 2 invocations of doit have their own memory space in the stack. If you want the two thread operating on one object, try pass an argument to the method. like doit(t)

Comment: @GingerJim - that won't work, because parameter references are copied to local members - `t = Hash.new` will not change `t` in another invocation of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`t` is a local variable of `doit`, it is declared only in the *scope* of the method. Each execution receives it own `t`.

If you want to *share* `t`, declare it as an instance member `@t`:

```
def doit
    @t = Hash.new
    puts @t.object_id
    loop do
      sleep 1
      puts @t.object_id
    end
end

t1 = Thread.new { doit }
t2 = Thread.new { doit }

t1.join
t2.join
```

Now your output would look like this:

```
15223760
15223580
15223580
15223580
15223580
15223580
15223580
15223580
15223580
15223580
15223580
```

Comment: “Private member” isn’t the correct term, “local variable” is.

Comment: Ah, your and Andrew's answers have put me on the right track. Of course, it is due to the scope, and has nothing to do with threading. OK, so each invocation is located somewhere else in memory, as naturally the two are executing simultaneously. As you posted first, I will accept your answer. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Threading has nothing to do with it. `t` is a local variable initialized on each call to `doit`—so each call gets its own `t`. Note that removing the threading gives the same results, albeit not interleaved:

```
def doit
  t = Hash.new
  t.object_id
end

doit #=> 21329316
doit #=> 21327684
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes total sense. Uri answered first, so I will accept his answer, but +1 to you anyway. Thank you.